# Implementing video editing suites with windows azure

Tags: windows, video, azure, edit

I am a student and preparing a presentation on azure services. My presentation focuses on what services could be provided to a film company migrating to the cloud. In particular I am wondering about the feasibility of offering high end video editing services online so that a film crew could access video data and edit from remote locations in the world. Specifically, would it be possible to implement video editing suites such as Adobe Premiere pro via azure? Any input would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like homework to me.

I'm not sure about video *editing* in the cloud, as these application suites tend to be very graphically focused, and bound to desktop computers (although there are some exceptions to this rule).

Azure can support the film industry in two main ways:

1. Rendering video animations (for example) by distributing rendering tasks out to a grid of computers. This work tends to be required in bursts, so being able to switch on/off a large number of computers in the cloud reduces the capital cost. [Read about Pixar's RenderMan on Azure](http://thenextweb.com/microsoft/2010/10/28/microsoft-and-pixar-team-up-to-bring-renderman-on-azure/)
2. [Windows Azure Media Services](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/features/media-services/) provides video encoding and delivery services, which makes it easy to distrubute and protect video content across a large number of devices (like iPhone, XBox, Flash etc..) and geographically (i.e. cached around the world).

What could also be suitable for your scenario is [Blob Storage](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/blob-storage/). A low cost, high availability file storage system. You could upload video content in one part of the world, which could then be made available to other team members in another part of the world.

Comment: Hi, sorry, this would have been useful. You were right it was a presentation in University. I actually discussed some of the things you mention. Thanks for your input and apologies for not replying sooner. I had not checked back after the question was marked as being not constructive.